# Posting multiple data in IoT gateway Thingsboard

Tags: cassandra, thingsboard

I just now started using Thingsboard and I came across this one,https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/getting-started/. I have implemented it but the problems that I'm facing are,

1.I can transmit only one Key-value pair. How can I transmit multiple key-value sensor data?

2.Also if there is any other way to access the Cassandra Database so that I can retrieve all mine data to Thingsboard.

Please help. Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, humidity, temperature, gas.

In this case you use one access token/single mqtt session and send data in single json like this

```
{"humidity":42.2, "temperature":23.3, "gas":45}
```

If you have multiple sensors attached to single device, send them like this

```
{"sensorA.humidity":42.2, "sensorB.temperature":23.3, "sensorC.gas":45}
```

Available topics are static and listed here: 
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#telemetry-upload-api

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two very different things.

**1) You can transmit more key-value pairs at once** by correctly mapping the gateway incoming messages. I suppose you are working with MQTT protocol. The default mapping for this protocol is specified in */etc/tb-gateway/conf/mqtt-config.json*. This file specifies how to translate the incoming MQTT messages from the broker into the ThingsBoard key-value format, before sending to the server instance of ThingsBoard. 
To map more than one reading from sensor, you can do somethings like this:

```
{
  "brokers": [
    {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 1883,
      "ssl": false,
      "retryInterval": 5000,
      "credentials": {
        "type": "anonymous"
      },
      "mapping": [
        {
          "topicFilter": "WeatherSensors",
          "converter": {
            "type": "json",
            "filterExpression": "",
            "deviceNameJsonExpression": "${$.WeatherStationName}",
            "timeout": 120000,
            "timeseries": [
              {
                "type": "double",
                "key": "temperature",
                "value": "${$.temperature}"
              },
              {
                "type": "double",
                "key": "humidity",
                "value": "${$.humidity}"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, if you send a message like `{"WeatherStationName":"test", "temperature":25, "humidity":40}` to the topic `WeatherSensors` you will see the two key-value pairs in ThingsBoard server, in a device named "test".

**2) The best way to access data stored in the internal ThingsBoard server** is via [REST API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/), so that you can query any ThingsBoard instance with the same piece of code regardless of the technology used for the database (Cassandra, PostgreSQL, etc.). You can find a Python example in this [repo](https://github.com/AbCthings/thingsboard-data-migration).
The alternative is to use a specific query language for the database, such as SQL for PostgreSQL or CQL for Cassandra.